# Click on view behind button if it's not clickable (isClickable = false)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, ontouchlistener

I have a recycler with rows of buttons. 
These buttons are only reused for styling purposes and set to isClickable = false.
The buttons are laied out in a grid view in order to dynamically handle any number of buttons.
When I click anywhere on a row i want to trigger a onClickListener set on each row parent view.

I tried a setting a empty Relative View over the entire view and setting the onClickListener on it. No result.

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_base_row_dark"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/grid_10x"
    android:stateListAnimator="@drawable/selector_elevation_button">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/answerContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_8x"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_3x"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_1x">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/gridAnswerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/answerQuestionTitleTextView"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_2x"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_1x"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/grid_1x"
            android:columnWidth="120dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/grid_1x"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tool:visibility="visible" />

    </RelativeLayout>

   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/answerRowClickableArea"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

in adapter:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, position: Int) {

answerRowClickableArea.setOnClickListener(goToIndex(rowPosition))

}
```

I also tried overriding GestureDetector.OnGestureListener in my toggle button class, telling the button to only consume touch events if it's not clickable. 
My intention was that if the button did not consume the touch event it would be passed down to the parent with the onClickListener.

```
class OvalToggleButton(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : ToggleButton(context, attributeSet), GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
    override fun onShowPress(e: MotionEvent?) {
    }

    override fun onSingleTapUp(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        return !isClickable
    }

    override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onFling(e1: MotionEvent?, e2: MotionEvent?, velocityX: Float, velocityY: Float): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun onScroll(e1: MotionEvent?, e2: MotionEvent?, distanceX: Float, distanceY: Float): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun onLongPress(e: MotionEvent?) {
    }
 }
```

Still no result.

Is there a simple way to "ignore" views and touch whats behind?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to set The layout of your row clickable ?

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout.setClickable(true);
```

Comment: yes, but it seams to me that the row layout is in the bottom layer and thus the button consumes the touches.

Comment: Actually I've already use a clickable  linear layout use a button on it, but no in a recyclerView. You still can use `setEnable()` method on your button, but not sure of it.

Comment: Ok, I see. I have a few factors that might have contributed to the problem.
1. I was using toggle buttons
2. I had an recycler within a recycler

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by putting my answerRowClickableArea inside of the same relative layout and aligning each edge with my grid view.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_base_row_dark"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/grid_10x"
    android:stateListAnimator="@drawable/selector_elevation_button">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/answerContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_8x"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_3x"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_1x">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/gridAnswerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/answerQuestionTitleTextView"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_2x"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_1x"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/grid_1x"
                android:columnWidth="120dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/grid_1x"
                android:visibility="gone"
                tool:visibility="visible" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/answerRowClickableArea"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/gridAnswerView"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/gridAnswerView"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@id/gridAnswerView"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/gridAnswerView" />

        </RelativeLayout> 
</RelativeLayout>
```